# Bridge between Delphi or C code and Python script

Tags: python

I have a Delphi Win32 program. I want to "expose" somehow app structures and procedures via Python module. E.g. module `my_api` must expose public items for my app structures/methods. This module must "sit" in memory only.

Then I want, in the same app, to call Python scripts (using Python dll) which can import `my_api` and call my app methods.
How to do it.

Comment: I just noticed that you mentioned Delphi here. You will be going through two bridges to talk between Delphi and Python. For example, to call a Python function from Delphi, you need to use the Delphi FFI to access the C function `PyObject_Call`; to expose a Delphi function to Python, you need to first wrap it up to be callable from C, then wrap that up for Python. I haven't used Delphi in a very long time, but if this is a hassle, you might want to consider using Delphi.NET (that's a thing, right?) and IronPython instead.

Comment: Tks, I ll use Delphi way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for two things here, which often go together.

First, you want to *extend* the Python interpreter, adding types and functions and so forth that Python code can use.

Second, you want to *embed* the Python interpreter in your app, so it can run Python scripts (which can use your extension modules).

Assuming you want to use CPython (the usual Python interpreter), the tutorial [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](http://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/index.html) is part of the docs.

You may want to look at other options that help make the extending side easier—for example, you can use Cython to write the bridge code in a near-Python language instead of C, or Boost.Python to write it in nice C++ that takes care of most of the boilerplate for you, or SWIG to try to generate it automatically, or `ctypes` to avoid writing a bridge in the first place. But it's worth learning the underlying mechanism first.

Answer (score 2):

You may have heard of Python 4 Delphi by now, and if you haven't you can look it up here. https://code.google.com/p/python4delphi/. There are quite a few tutorials on the internet e,g http://www.atug.com/andypatterns/pythonDelphiTalk.htm